# Какой шрифт используется в логотипе Helix Ultimate?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой шрифт используется в словах "HELIX" и "ULTIMATE"?

https://www.joomshaper.com/joomla-templates/helixultimate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: StackOverflow - не место для подобных вопросов. Воспользуйтесь сервисами по идентификации шрифтов или поищите сообщества дизайнеров.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минута ушла на поиск :)

```
Geometos Neue Extra Bold
```

---

Я ошибся. Вот тот шрифт который вам нужен

Comment: А как Вы искали?

Comment: Я ошибся, приняв другой текст за желаемый... Нужный же шрифт я нашел с помощью сервисов распознавание шрифта по картинке

Comment: Cocogoose Classic ExtraBo - такой ещё может быть очень похож

Comment: Спасибо        ........